# Why are the pixel colors not correct in OpenGL ES 2.0 on Android?

Tags: java, android, opengl-es, textures

(Edit: I tried a sample that merely painted a triangle without any texture or shaders and only OpenGL-ES 1.1 on my device and could see the same artifacts. I tried the same sample in the emulator and there were no artifacts there at all. Could this be a Tegra 2 issue or do I need to set a specific state or something which is not necessary in the emulator ?)

I am rendering a pixel correct square on the screen but when I make a screengrab and look at the pixel then some of them are slightly off like antialised or filtered or something like that. You only see it when you zoom in on them but that is not the point. I want to do some math in the pixel shader and if the pixels are slightly off and thats no good to me. I need them exactly like in the bitmap I put them in.

Here is an enlarged screengrab of the problem. Around the white Line the dark values are slightly brighter than they should be:

[image]

I already tried:

```
GLES20.glDisable(GLES20.GL_DITHER);
GLES20.glTexParameteri(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_2D, GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GLES20.GL_NEAREST );
GLES20.glTexParameteri(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_2D, GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GLES20.GL_NEAREST );
GLES20.glTexParameteri(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_2D, GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GLES20.GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE );
GLES20.glTexParameteri(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_2D, GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GLES20.GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE );
```

but it had no effect. The pixels are just slightly off. Its easy to see between a dark and white pixel because the dark pixel next to it is slightly brighter and checking the r,g,b values with a painting program shows me that too.

Could someone please assist me with this ?

Some more info:

My device's CPU is a Tegra 2.0. I render a 256x256 square exactly into 256x256 pixels (I checked that by taking a screen grab with eclipse DDMS). Transparency is off and the bitmap has an alpha value of 255 for each pixel. I created the surface as a 32bit surface with alpha with:

```
    glSurface.setEGLConfigChooser(8, 8, 8, 8, 0, 0);
```

I simplified the code but still can see the problem when I render with following shaders:

```
    String vshaderquad =    "attribute vec4 a_pos;              \n" +   //  in      position
                            "attribute vec2 a_tex;              \n" +   //  in      Texture coordinates
                            "varying vec2 vtex;                 \n" +   //  out     Texture coordinates
                            "void main(void) {                  \n" +
                            "   gl_Position = vec4(a_pos);      \n" +
                            "   vtex = a_tex;                   \n" +
                            "}";

    String fshaderquad =    "precision mediump  float;                      \n" +
                            "varying vec2       vtex;                       \n" +
                            "uniform sampler2D  samp0;                      \n" +
                            "void main() {                                  \n" +
                            "   gl_FragColor = texture2D(samp0, vtex);      \n" +
                            "}";
```

and commands:

```
GLES20.glActiveTexture(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE0);
GLES20.glBindTexture(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_2D, mapid[0]);
GLES20.glTexParameteri(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_2D, GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GLES20.GL_NEAREST );
GLES20.glTexParameteri(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_2D, GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GLES20.GL_NEAREST );
GLES20.glTexParameteri(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_2D, GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GLES20.GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE );
GLES20.glTexParameteri(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_2D, GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GLES20.GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE );
GLES20.glUniform1i(handlesampler0, 0);
GLES20.glDisable(GLES20.GL_DITHER);



GLES20.glViewport(0, 0, screenx, screeny);

float screenx = (float)ddimx;
float screeny = (float)ddimy;
//
vdata.put(0*4+0,     0.0f * (2.0f/screenx));
vdata.put(0*4+1,   256.0f * (2.0f/screeny));
vdata.put(0*4+2,     0.0f * (1.0f/256f));
vdata.put(0*4+3,   256.0f * (1.0f/256f));
//  
vdata.put(1*4+0,     0.0f * (2.0f/screenx));
vdata.put(1*4+1,     0.0f * (2.0f/screeny));
vdata.put(1*4+2,     0.0f * (1.0f/256f));
vdata.put(1*4+3,     0.0f * (1.0f/256f));
//  
vdata.put(2*4+0,   256.0f * (2.0f/screenx));
vdata.put(2*4+1,   256.0f * (2.0f/screeny));
vdata.put(2*4+2,   256.0f * (1.0f/256f));
vdata.put(2*4+3,   256.0f * (1.0f/256f));
//  
vdata.put(3*4+0,   256.0f * (2.0f/screenx));
vdata.put(3*4+1,     0.0f * (2.0f/screeny));
vdata.put(3*4+2,   256.0f * (1.0f/256f));
vdata.put(3*4+3,     0.0f * (1.0f/256f));

GLES20.glDrawArrays(GLES20.GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP, 0, 4);
```

PS: The slight color change is not really visible without extreme zooming in but I want to do calculations with the values and that means they just have to be precise.

Edit: I added a full resolution image. The colors on the lines should go from (0,0,0) to (255,255,255) and are  inverse to the background gradient. I made this image only to test the accuracy of the texture and there I found the problem that its not really precise. You have to zoom in though to make out the differences that is why I posted the enlarged image as well. Note: The coordinates are different than in the code posted above but the problem is the same (I tried different onscreen coordinates and the problem persists).

[image]

Comment: A screengrab would be great to show the problem, but from what you write I suspect it's [dithering](http://www.curious-creature.org/2010/12/08/bitmap-quality-banding-and-dithering/). It's a postprocessing, so it should not affect your pixel shaders.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your reply and I added an image to better show the problem. I also do not think that it is merely a postprocessing error because I do some calculations in the shaders and the expected values were off and point to that as being the problem.

Comment: I ask as an Android dunce: is there any way you're using a PenTile display and reading back colours that are calculated from the actual display elements?

Comment: Its a sony device with a normal tft (could be ips, mva or even super-tft because it has relatively good viewing angles and doesn't invert the colors like normal tn panels) and I don't think its a display with a pentile matrix. I take the screenshots with eclipse DDMS which I think works on the memory buffer directly. I think that if there are any pentile related changes they should not be on that level. But I am not certain.

Comment: Not only there are "antialiasing" effects near the line, the entire background is also a horizontal gradient (from 37 -> 44). Is is supposed to be like this in the source texture?

Comment: yes, sorry I didn't clarify that. There is supposed to be a gradient. the whole texture is 256x256 and the values are from rgb 0,0,0 on one side to 255,255,255 on the other. with 2 lines going through it diagonally with the inverse color. I made it that way to verify the values of the pixels and there I discovered the slight discrepancies. I uploaded a complete image at http://postimage.org/image/ovh9egdon/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok, I think I have found the solution.

As I already wrote I made a screenshot with the eclipse DDMS and that seems to be causing the problem. That screenshot is not the exact framebuffer but some kind of smoothing/anti-aliasing is going on there.

This seems not to be the result of the DDMS itself but only appears to happen when used on my actual device. When I tried it with the emulator that problem didn't appear so it might be that my device has a pentile screen (its only released in Japan so far and I found no info material so confirming or denying it, but its sony and sony did use pentile displays in devices) or maybe it has to do with the tegra 2 chip or maybe its some kind of compression that happens when the image is being transfered or maybe for some other reason altogether.

Either way, when I use the following function I can save screenshots that are absolutely perfect as it takes the OpenGL-ES 2.0 Framebuffer and saves it into a png file that I can then easily transfer with a batch file ("adb pull /mnt/sdcard/info/Testfile.txt") and view on my computer:

```
public boolean SaveFrameBuffer(int x, int y)
{   try
    {   IntBuffer   pinbuffer   = IntBuffer.allocate(x*y*4);
        IntBuffer   poutbuffer  = IntBuffer.allocate(x*y*4);
        int         i,j,z;
        int []      pin         = pinbuffer.array();
        int []      pout        = poutbuffer.array();
        //
        GLES20.glReadPixels(0, 0, x, y, GLES20.GL_RGBA, GLES20.GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, pinbuffer);            
        for(i=0;i<y;i++)
        {   for(j=0;j<x;j++)
            {   z = pin[(y-1-i)*x+j];
                pout[i*x+j] = (z & 0xff000000) | ((z >> 16) & 0x000000ff) | ((z << 16) & 0x00ff0000) | (z  & 0x0000ff00); 
            }
        }
        Bitmap map = Bitmap.createBitmap(x, y, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
        map.setPixels(pout, 0, x, 0,0, x, y);
        OutputStream stream = new FileOutputStream("/sdcard/info/test.png");
        map.compress(CompressFormat.PNG, 100, stream);
        stream.close();
        return true;
    } catch (Exception e)
    {   e.printStackTrace();
        return false;
    }
}
```